# speex codec - packets per second

Tags: networking, voip, codec

how many packets per second if we use

> Speex Codec - 16kHz - H.323,SIP

in Ekiga Softphone?
and how to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Speex, [the frame size is always 20ms](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/speex-dev/2005-September/003694.html), so to minimize delay, it should/will always generate 50 packets per second. Only the packet sizes will vary.

The codec in itself doesn't forbid merging multiple frames inside one packet, but that will raise the delay considerably and would probably not be a good thing for a soft phone to do.

All the details you need and more are also available in the [Speex RTP profile docs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-herlein-speex-rtp-profile-02).